# Any simple sample of EVR custom mixer?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Is there any simple sample of writing a custom mixer for the  Media Foundation enhanced video renderer?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not exactly a full-blown sample like they have for the EVR Presenter plug-in, but the following page does seem relatively comprehensive and useful:

[Enhanced Video Renderer - Custom Mixers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701624)

> This topic describes how to write a custom mixer for the enhanced video renderer (EVR). You can use a custom mixer with either the Media Foundation EVR media sink, or the DirectShow EVR filter. For more information about mixers and presenters, see Enhanced Video Renderer.

In fact, all of Windows Media Foundation API is quite well documented, I find. Too bad the product itself has had such a hard time getting adopted. I guess DirectShow works just fine for most tasks, so it's proved difficult to dethrone over the past decade. And while I realize COM is a tried-and-true workhorse, it hardly felt like a futuristic choice when they based MF on it in 2006.

Note also that the pervasive "asynchronous calling" requirement that MF exposed was heavy-handed and misguided, especially given the hindsight of today's mature, lightweight and elegant Task-based async.

There's also a chicken and egg problem when your fancy new API is not backwards-compatible with the extensive 3rd party ecosystem out there, as well as confounding facts like the lack of 1st-party, out-of-the box support for trivial/basic functionality like MKV, FLV, and WEBM playback; even now, a decade later, there's no plausible solution to that from anybody. (Microsoft's own media players typically try MF first, and fall back to DirectShow for formats that fail, meaning they have to maintain full support for both platforms internally)

Returning to your inquiry, a related question would be whether the EVR's standard mixer has been updated to support asynchronous MFT mode, which Microsoft quietly introduced a few years back. If, so, that would possibly offer great opportunities for working with it more flexibly, as opposed to having to swap in a whole new custom module.

Remember, that mixer is just an ordinary MFT, so you can query its capability flags like any other transform. While you're at it, you'll also want to see if it has kept up with another recent MF development, namely, MFTs which can negotiate the sharing of D3D9 hardware buffers with their pipeline neighbors (in lieu of sample passing in system memory). I believe they can even use Direct3D 11 buffers now too.